# Can tensorboard display an interactive plot or 3D plot

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard, visualize, tensorboardx

I have to visualize the interactive 3D plot on tensorboard. Can the tensorboard visualize this or is there any way to display this on tensorboard.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the mesh plugin on TensorBoard. It'll allow you to create a visualization similar to those found on Three.js . You pass in the vertices, colors, and faces of the 3D data and TensorBoard will create a 3D interactive visualization. There are other options such as projections but those are mainly used for embeddings.